# How do I write a single backslash in a JSON file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, fs, backslash

I need my json (text utf-8) file to have a single **\** like below

```
{
  "pageid": "page\/123412341234"
}
```

**Unfortunately, sketchapp requires the file in that format. So please let me know if there is any way to remove the escape char before writing it to the file.**

Now I am using this e.g function to write my file

```
exports.writeJSON = (jsonObject, fileLocation) => {
  let data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
  fs.writeFileSync(fileLocation, data);
};
```

where

```
jsonObject =  {
  "pageid": "page\\/123412341234"
};
```

The output file I am getting has two **\\** like below:

```
{
  "pageid": "page\\/123412341234"
}
```

How can I make it only one **\**. I think `JSON.stringify` is adding the escape char and that is getting dumped in the file as well.

**Is there any way in Javascript to remove the extra escape backslash?**

Comment: "to remove the extra escape backslash" --- it's a wrong way. Instead you should understand where and why you get an extra character.

Comment: `"page\\/123412341234"` - this is a string literal that is equal to the `"page\/123412341234"` string. So in JSON you have the same string with a backslash escaped because JSON requires to be so. If you remove a slash- the resulting string after decoding would be `"page/123412341234"`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. `'a\/b'` is exactly the same as `'a/b'`, because it's treated as an unnecessary escaping of the forward slash character. Why would you want your file to contain an unnecessary escape?

Comment: Unfortunately, sketchapp requires the file in that format. So please let me know if there is any way to remove the escape char before writing it to the file.

Comment: @Pratyush are you *absolutely* sure it won't accept `{
  "pageid": "page/123412341234"
}` ?

Comment: I'd go to their bugtracker - this either is a bug or the format they accept is not JSON.